# Quiz app score resetting

Tags: php

Hi here my processing file for my quizzer application. My code is realizing the answer to every question, however everytime I click the right answer and it sets the score to one. It goes to the next question, and then its resetting the session score to 0, and then adding one. The result is if I have a score of 3, I actually get a score of one. Where do i put the score variable so it doesent keep resetting everytime i process? If i `echo $_SESSION['score']`; at the end, I always get 0 or 1.

```
  $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $number = $_POST['number'];
        $selected_choice = $_POST['choice'];
        $next = $number + 1;

        // get total questions


        $query = "SELECT * FROM questions";


        // get result

        $results = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        $total = mysqli_num_rows($results);

        // query to get right answer


        $query = "SELECT * FROM choices WHERE question_number = $number AND is_correct = 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);


        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);




        // set correct choice

        $correct_choice = $row['id'];
        // Compare

        if($correct_choice == $selected_choice)
        {
            // answer is correct
            $_SESSION['score']++;

        }


        // check is last question
        if($number == $total)
        {
            header("Location:final.php");
            exit();
        } else
        {
            header("Location:question.php?n=$next");
        }
    }
```

which processes the question.php

```
           <ul class = "choices">




                   <?php
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($choices)): ?>
                   <li><input name = "choice" type = "radio" value = "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" /> <?php  echo $row['text']; ?></li>
                    <?php  endwhile  ?>


                </ul>


            <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit">
            <input type = "hidden" name = "number" value = "<?php echo $number ?>" >

        </form>
```

Comment: Look at the very first line of code in your page.  What do you suspect that line of code is doing?

Comment: Resetting the score to zero. But without that line score isnt defined to start anywhere right? Don't we need to start at 0? I'm not sure how to implement this

Answer (score 1):

You are just saying yourself, that you reset the score to 0 on a new page load.

```
$_SESSION['score'] = 0;
```

And then you either do nothing to it or add 1 - so how could that score be anything different than 0 or 1? Stop resetting the score.

Comment: Thats the thing. Don't I need to give it a default value of 0? Otherwise score is undefined?

Comment: Yes, but you need to check if score is defined - and only then define it with a default value. See David's added code.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the value to 0 every time you load the page:

```
$_SESSION['score'] = 0;
```

Instead, check if the value exists before setting it.  Perhaps something as simple as:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['score'])) {
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
}
```

That way whenever the page loads it will set the value only if it hasn't already been set.

Comment: How come when I take out $_SESSION['score'] = 0;, it works? I mean I am not defining score to start at 0, but still the program realizes score is 0? The heck?

Comment: @cresjoy: I guess I don't know enough about the details of PHP to speak with any authority as to what might happen when you try to `++` increment a value that isn't set.  Some debugging and testing should be able to find the information you're looking for.  Either way though, I wouldn't rely on something like that.  Better to be explicit in the logic than to cleverly use less obvious functionality.  (Basically, the last thing you want to do with working code is look at it and not understand why it's working.)

Comment: Thats true. Thanks, I'm guessing it auto sets a variable to 0 then.

Comment: @cresjoy: It would appear that adding 1 to something that's undefined results in 1.  Test:  `echo $foo;  $foo++;  echo $foo;`  The variable is never defined, so there are notices generated, but the result at the end is still `1`.

Comment: Hi I have another question. My quizz app is done! I have added in an add question page. However how it works is it adds 1 to the previous question and makes that the question number. For example if there are two default questions, the next question number is three, and you can add the question, choices, and select which is the right answer. Now this works great however say I make 3 questions then delete 3 and 4. My page currently works by going from question 1,2,3,4,5. But it would break in the case some pages between are deleted. How can I account for this?